# How to get list of failed invoices of a customer in STRIPE API?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, cakephp-2.5

I am working in cakephp framework and have integrated stripe api for billing and payments. Now i need to get a list of failed invoices of a customer to retry those invoices payment. I have checked Stripe API documentation but could not find a solution.

Please help.

Comment: What have you already tried? Please, add some code to your question.

Comment: You can list all invoices, check for ones that failed and go from there: https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/list

Comment: @PaulAsjes this service is used to get all invoices. is this the only way to do this. I mean is there any way to get only failed transactions.

Comment: @cnnr i have no idea which service is used to get only failed invoices.

Comment: There's no way to list only failed invoices, you'll have to list them all and then filter through the results.

Comment: @PaulAsjes Ok. thanks. I will do it this way.